# multi touch functions needed?

Tags: objective-c

I am not sure which are the functions to implement multi touch in cocos.? could anyone show me a demo?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a view then use touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesCancelled and touchesEnded callbacks to implement your custom behaviour.

[Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

I can't point you to a demo, but you'll also need to make sure that you set multipleTouchesEnabled to YES and find some way to keep track of the touches.

[This is a useful starting point for tracking the touches](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW14)